# My desktop browser innerWidth is not the same as my android phone innerWidth after rotate to landscape and back again?

Tags: css

I have some questions...
In my browser on desktop, if I have the width of browser 360px (seen from the chrome dev tol), and console.log() innerWidth and outerWidth it returns

```
innerWidth: 360px;
outerWidth: 376px;
```

If I console.log() them on my android phone, it's:

```
innerWidth: 360px;
outerWidth: 360px;
```

I understand that. But now to the problem, when I rotate landscape mode on android, and rotate it back to portrait mode, it returns:

```
innerWidth: 588px
outerWidth: 360px
```

Why is innerWidth bigger now? And I can't use outerWidth because in desktop browser it will be some pixels bigger(16px here).
Is there any other options to get the same width from both the browswer on desktop and in mobile?

Comment: Can you give us a live example?

Comment: what kind of units are you using? do you have meta tag?

Comment: I was using media query for mobile version, and also got a script that moves a div when the width <= 550px.  However, innerWidth or outerWidth is not the same as css media query widths? My 550px in media query was not the same as my 550px on JS width(inner/outer tested both). 

But what I did was lowering the width on my JS function, and got it working pretty good. :)